Minimal Prerequesites to Study Section 3.1 (Cohomology Groups) in Hatcher
I want to take Algebraic Topology next year, and in the meantime, I thought it would be an excellent opportunity to listen to a topology reading group organized by some older students. So far, I have only taken a general topology course that covered point set topology in Munkres and Chapter 1 of Hatcher (The Fundamental Group, Van Kampen's Theorem, and Covering Spaces). In its itinerary, the group also plans to discuss homology and cohomology.
Right now, I'm reading Section 2.1 (Simplical and Singular Homology) in Hatcher. The material seems to make enough sense that I can follow along with the examples and definitions. Of course, I'm probably missing most of the big picture, and I don't think I'll be able to complete the chapter exercises any time soon.
Question: If all I hope to gain is a cursory understanding of introductory homology and cohomology, is it possible to skip from Section 2.1 to Section 3.1 (Cohomology Groups) without covering the more advanced homology sections (2.2-2.3)?
Thank you so much

I think you should really try to read 2.2 and do some exercises.

Should I focus on the Mayer-Vietoris Sequences (pg 149) in Section 2.2? I was also interested in Bott and Tu for a more geometric lens, and they start discussing these sequences around page 20. If it's the equivalent of the Van Kampen theorem in homology, I assume it's pretty foundational, right?

If you really mean "cursory," as in "hasty and therefore not thorough or detailed" (definition provided by Google) then sure, Section 2.1 of Hatcher is enough. The descriptions of an axiomatic approach for cohomology, cellular cohomology, and the Mayer-Vietoris sequence, all of which appear at the end of Section 3.1, will not be very meaningful.
I will note that Section 2.2 provides useful tools for computation and theory, and Section 2.3 is brief but useful (an axiomatic approach to homology). If you're not familiar with the basics of category theory, you should be. That is also part of Section 2.3.
You could read Sections 2.2 and 2.3 in parallel with Section 3.1 if you don't have time to read the material from Chapter 2 before you get to Chapter 3.
